# Combining two field into one Text content wpf

Tags: wpf

I want to combine Name and ID of the song in the header of Song. Would it be possible if I have:

```
Song
{
   public string Name {get; set;}
   public int ID {get; set;}
}
```

I want to bind them into the Header of an Expander. At the moment, for binding with only one property. it is like this:

```
<Expander Foreground="#FFF4E7CA"  Header="{Binding Song.Name}" FontWeight="Bold">
</Expander>
```

But I want to be some thing like this:

```
Header = "{Binding Some.Name, Song.ID}"
```

Is it possible somehow then? and if yes, how?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Something like this:

```
<Expander ...>
  <Expander.Header>
    <TextBlock>
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding Song.Name}"/>
      <TextBlock Text=" "/>
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding Sond.ID}"/>
    </TextBlock>
  </Expander.Header>
  ...
</Expander>
```

Comment: I tried this and I got: Object can accept only one child. I can not add multiple 'Run' tags

Comment: Are you sure it's a `TextBlock` and not a `TextBox` ?

Comment: I forgot of adding TextBlock.I Just have added it but I got another error: A binding can not be set on the Text property of type Run.

Comment: Do I need to use this control 'bindableRun; http://www.fortes.com/2007/bindablerun

Answer (score 5):

You could either

1) expose a new property on your view model and bind to that

```
Song
{
   public string Name {get; set;}
   public int ID {get; set;}
   public string Header {get { return string.Format("{0} {1}", Name, ID); } }
}
```

2) use a multi-binding with a string format

```
<TextBlock.Text>
    <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0} {1}">
        <Binding Path="Song.Name"/>
        <Binding Path="Song.Id"/>
    </MultiBinding>
</TextBlock.Text>
```

3) If you're using WPF4, then `Run` is bindable so the answer regarding using `Run` would then work.

Comment: solution 1 I can not modify inside the control. Solution 2 does not work with WPF 3.5. I can not change the target .net framework to 4. thanks for an overview of the solutions. It helps me a lot

Comment: Solution #2 is invalid in .net 4.  Source is not a bindable property.  The proper code is <Binding Path="Song.Name" />

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use [the multibinding class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.multibinding.aspx)